# How Visual Studio discover NuGets with source symbols?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, debug-symbols

I prepared a symbol package successfully using `dotnet pack`'s `--include-symbols` and `--include-source` switches. Now I wonder how to tell Visual Studio to use that package when trying to step into code of the corresponding non-symbol one.

I tried to place the symbol package to a local folder and configuring solution-level `nuget.config` file to use this folder as a package source. Idea is that there is maybe some name convention that looks for packages like `{name}.symbols` in all configured packages sources... but that doesn't work.

Oficial docs (especially the older ones) are talking a lot about configuring "Symbol Servers", but if I understand correctly, that's something different and older, right? If I wanted to set-up an internal symbol server, I wouldn't do that through NuGet. (I really don't want to set up an internal symbol server.)

They are also suggesting to push to `smbsrc.net`, but I can't do that with internal code, obviously. Also, I can't believe there are hard-coded URLs in .NET toolbox.

Comment: use [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) this adds a json to the PDB to show where it can find the source

Comment: Will investigate, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to meaningfully use source included by `dotnet build`.

There are alternatives though:

- [SourceLink](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink) offers a way to configure mapping between source code build paths and HTTP locations. Unfortunately, that does not work for private repositories without a specific support for source control server authentication method. Bitbucket Server, for example, is not yet supported.
- You can embed sources [directly into PDBs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12625). I will probably go that way.